# Minimum vertices to remove from a graph so that no path exists between two given vertices anymore

Tags: graphs, planar-graphs, connected-components

Given an undirected graph $G=\{V, E\}$ with its vertices numbered from $1$ to $V$, given two vertices $s$ and $t$ $(1 \leq s \lt t \leq V)$, what is the minimum number of vertices (except $s$ and/or $t$) that we need to remove (we also remove the edges associated with those vertices) so that there doesn't exist any path between $s$ and $t$ anymore?

If it's difficult to solve under general constraints, can it then at least be solved efficiently in case the maximum possible degree of any vertex in the graph is $4$?

My current progress: Maybe it can be solved by using the BFS/DFS numbers obtained from starting BFS/DFS from $s$?

Comment: Asked on cstheory: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2877/minimum-cut-through-vertices-nodes-not-edges

Comment: I doubt that it matters that $s < t$ (rather than $t < s$).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is known as *minimum vertex cut* or *minimum vertex separator*. There is a simple reduction from this problem to the directed minimum edge cut, adopted from [notes by Locke](http://euler.math.fau.edu/locke/Menger.htm).

The new graph contains vertices $(s,0),(t,1)$, and $(u,0),(u,1)$ for any $u \neq s,t$, as well as the following edges:

- For every $\{s,u\} \in E$: the edge $(s,0) \to (u,1)$.
- For every $\{u,v\} \in E$ (where $u,v \neq s,t$): the edges $(u,0) \to (v,1)$ and $(v,0) \to (u,1)$.
- For every $\{t,u\} \in E$: the edge $(u,0) \to (t,1)$.
- For every $u \neq s,t$: the edge $(u,1) \to (u,0)$.

A path $s \to x \to y \to z \to t$ in $G$ lifts to the following directed path in the new graph from $(s,0)$ to $(t,1)$:
$$
(s,0) \to (x,1) \to (x,0) \to (y,1) \to (y,0) \to (z,1) \to (z,0) \to (t,1).
$$
As can be seen, in order to realize an $s$-$t$ path, we need to use the edges $(u,1) \to (u,0)$ for all vertices $u$ appearing internally in the path.

We now give unit weight to the edges $(u,1) \to (u,0)$ and infinite (or large enough) weight to all other edges, and look for a minimum edge cut between $(s,1)$ to $(t,0)$; this can be solved by computing a maximum flow. A minimum edge cut in the new graph is the same as a minimum vertex cut in $G$.